# Why am I getting a nil value (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, class, initialization

I have 2 classes, When initializing the 'Shop' class I am giving the class a currency. How can I have "@checkout_currency" from my second class adopt the '@currency' value from the first class? @checkout_currency currently equals nil and I want it to equal "USD"

Here are my classes.

First..

```
require_relative 'convert'

class Shop

  DEFAULT_CURRENCY = "USD"

  def initialize(currency = DEFAULT_CURRENCY,
                 convert = Convert.new)
    @currency = currency
    @convert = convert

  end

  def self.currency
    @currency
  end

end
```

Second..

```
require_relative 'shop'

class Convert

  attr_reader :checkout_currency

  def initialize(checkout_currency = Shop.currency)
    @checkout_currency = checkout_currency
  end

end
```

Comment: The `@currency` variable in `Shop#currency` is different  from the one set in the constructor of `Shop`, but I think your whole design is broken: In shop.rb, you seem to _require_ convert.rb, and in convert.rb, you _require_ shop.rb. This is not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, defining a method with `self` will make it a method on the class rather than a method on any instance of the class. But `@currency` is an *instance variable* – it’s different for every *instance* of `Shop`, and not defined for the `Shop` class itself. What if you had 3 `Shop` objects with different currencies?

The thing that is really wrong is your composition of objects – is `Convert` something that `Shop` constructs, or is it something that must be passed in fully formed? If you restructure to either of these, your problem goes away.

```
class Shop
  def initialize(convert, currency=DEFAULT_CURRENCY)
    @convert = convert
    @currency = currency
  end
end

convert = Convert.new(Shop.DEFAULT_CURRENCY)
shop = Shop.new(convert)
```

Or maybe:

```
class Shop
  def initialize(currency=DEFAULT_CURRENCY, convert_class=Convert)
    @convert = convert_class.new(currency)
    @currency = currency
  end
end

shop = Shop.new
```